# Showing that $\sqrt{1+h}<1+\frac{h}{2}$ using mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have two, I believe, related exercises in my homework. I am uncomfortable with my reasoning even though I think its solid. I am hoping that someone can either point out the flaw or confirm the proof. The first exercise is as follows:

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in (0,1]$.

Let $h=f+g$ and consider $h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)$ which is greater than $0$ since $f'(x)>g'(x)$. From the corollary to the mean value theorem we know that our constructed function $h$ is both $1-1$ and is increasing since its derivative is strictly greater than $0$. Therefore, for any $x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $x_2>x_1$ we have $h(x_2)>h(x_1)$ or that $f(x_2)-g(x_2)>f(x_1)-g(x_1)$. We let $x_1=0$ (causing no problems since the inequality will hold for any $x_1 \in [0,1]$ and observe that 
            $$f(x_2)-g(x_2)>f(0)-g(0)=0 \Rightarrow f(x_2)>g(x_2)$$
         Since $x_2$ was any arbitrary value in $(0,1]$ we have that $f(x)>g(x) \,\, \forall x \in (0,1]$.

The problem that follows (the one I am uncomfortable with):

Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that
            $$\sqrt{1+h}<1+\frac{h}{2},$$
        for $h(0)$.\
We know that $\sqrt{1+0}=1+\frac{0}{2}$ and we consider $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+h}}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Clearly, $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+h}}<\frac{1}{2}$ for $h>0$. Let $f(x)=1+\frac{h}{2}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1+h}$. We observed that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ and $f(0)=g(0)$. Therefore, from the above result, we have that $f(x)>g(x)$.

Is everything solid and well founded?

Comment: It should be $h = f - g$ at the beginning of the third paragraph. Doesn't matter much though since the remaining are correct.

Comment: In the last paragraph it should be either $f(h) = 1+\frac{h}{2}$ or $f(x) = 1+\frac{x}{2}$. Same for $g$. In spite of some minor typos the whole proof looks sound.

Comment: Other than some typographical errors, your reasoning is sound.  But the second part does request use of the MVT and not the result from the first part.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what the possible values of $h$ are. Is it really supposed to be $h\gt 0$?  Or is it $h\ne 0$?  And as has already pointed out, the problem seems to ask for *direct use* of the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure if referring to the previous answer is sufficient for using the MVT or if I should try and do it explicitly?

Comment: I am not seeing how I would "directly" apply the mvt here

Comment: Can't you just prove it by squaring both sides, after which you subtract $h+1$ from both sides? you'll end up with $0<\dfrac{h^2}{4}$.